# Why isn't the script tag not working in my PHP

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

include("db_conn.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    
$library_id=$_POST['library_id'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM student_login WHERE library_id='$library_id' AND password='$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($count==0){

    $insert="INSERT INTO student_login (library_id,password) VALUES('$library_id','$password')";
    $result1=mysqli_query($conn,$insert);
    sleep(1);
    echo '<script>
            alert("Successfully Added Into Database");
            window.location.href="add_student.php";
        </script>';
    
    header("Location:add_student.php");

}
else{

    echo '<script>
            alert("ID and Password already exists");
            window.location.href="add_student.php";
        </script>';

    header("Location:add_student.php");

}

}

?>
```

I wanted the message pop up  in the chrome after checking the condition that if the student does not exists in database then the script in if statement should execute but if present then script in else part should execute but both are not working but the changes are made in database.

Comment: You can't echo **and** do a header-based redirect, that makes no sense. If you want a 1990s-style UI where you alert something in JS and then redirect, then you'll need to do the redirect in JS as well (using window.location)

Comment: does your browser block popups?